# How to fetch Input Class value from querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to this want to select following Class value  in the `querySelectorAll`.

```html
<input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Share" 
       data-li-auto-click-utrki="y=SHARE&u=reShareButton&n=reShareUpdate">
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll("input.btn-primary")`

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary]'); this worked for me i want to check the value as "Share"

Comment: First item matched value `document.querySelectorAll("input.btn-primary")[0].value` = Share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good Advice to start with jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers. With a combination of versatility and extensibility, jQuery has changed the way that millions of people write JavaScript.

```
$('input.btn-primary').val(); =>"Share" 


if ( $('input.btn-primary').val() === 'Share' ) {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: Thanks 
 $('body').on('click', '.btn-primary') its working can i check if it contains "Share" in the input class

Comment: if ( $('input.btn-primary').val() == 'Share' ) {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}

Comment: In JavaScript when comparing its advised to use === instead of == due type coercion.

Comment: @cobote's comment above doesn't require jquery!